For a real symmetric matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, if for any orthogonal matrix $U$, we have $U\Sigma U'= \Sigma$, then $\Sigma = tI$
For a real symmetric matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, if for any orthogonal matrix $U$, we have $U\Sigma U'= \Sigma$, then $\Sigma = tI$
I think this is correct, but I don't know how to prove it.

Write $\Sigma=VDV'$ where $V$ is orthogonal and $D$ diagonal. Then  $W=V'UV$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix which satisfies $WDW'=D.$ If $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)$ and if $T=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$ and $W=\mathrm{diag}(T,I_{n-2})$ then $WDW'=\mathrm{diag}(d_2,d_1\ldots,d_n)=D$. This proves $d_1=d_2.$ A similar $W$ shows $d_i=d_j.$ Therefore $D=d_1I_n$ and well as $\Sigma=d_1I_n.$
